# Why pandas dataframe doesn't change when i used it as a input of a function with multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, python-multiprocessing

I have a code like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A4", "A5", "A6", "A7"],
        "B": ["B4", "B5", "B6", "B7"],
        "C": ["C4", "C5", "C6", "C7"],
        "D": ["D4", "D5", "D6", "D7"],
    }
)

def changeDF(df):
    df['Signal'] = 0

changeDF(df1)
changeDF(df2)
```

when I run above, (changeDf) function add a column to df1 and df2 named 'Signal' with 0 values. but instead of run (changeDf) directly using multiprocessing like below it doesn't change any dfs.

```
s = [df1, df2]
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    res = pool.map(changeDF, s)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Change your function to return the modified data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializing `df1` & `df2` for multiprocessing means that you're making a copy.

Return your dataframe from the function and it'll work fine.

```
def changeDF(df):
    df['Signal'] = 0
    return(df)

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    df1, df2 = pool.map(changeDF, [df1, df2])
```

I would warn you that the serialization costs of this will certainly be higher than the benefit you get from multiprocessing.

Comment: You can just do `df1, df2 = pool.map(changeDF, [df1, df2])`. No need for the brackets `[df1, df2]` at the beginning of the line

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. I'm looking for a way to parallelize my calculation without copy a new version of my dataframes because these are very big dataframes and with copy might have trouble with RAM. Do you have any idea to parallelize its calculation without copy of these?

Comment: You should look into libraries built for that purpose. I would suggest dask.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function `changeDF` to be like this:

```
def changeDF(df):
    df['Signal'] = 0
    return df
```